# After mapping the result of the list is empty - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to apply logic and filter the list. But as a result getting empty list. Please take a look at the code and let me know where might be the issue.

Here is my filtering chain

```
return list
        .orEmpty()
        .filter {
            it?.orange?.contains("orange") ?: false
        }
        .take(6)
        .map { //<--- it is broken here
            NeededSampleData(
                it?.apple?.description,
                it?.description
            )
        }
```

Here is my data class that I am mapping to

```
data class NeededSampleData(val apple: String?, val lemon: String?)
```

Thats the list before filtering

```
  {
"data": {
  "items": {
    "__typename": "list",
    "list": [
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription1"
        },
        "orange": "orange1",
        "description": "extradescription1"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription2"
        },
        "orange": "orange2",
        "description": "extradescription2"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription3"
        },
        "orange": "orange3",
        "description": "extradescription3"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription4"
        },
        "orange": "orange4",
        "description": "extradescription4"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription5"
        },
        "orange": "orange5",
        "description": "extradescription5"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription6"
        },
        "orange": "orange6",
        "description": "extradescription6"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "apple",
        "apple": {
          "__typename": "description",
          "description": "somedescription7"
        },
        "orange": "orange7",
        "description": "extradescription7"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

}

I guess there is some issue in converting object from the list to `NeededSampleData` class. Maybe its because names of the variables in the data class does not fit with the response variables but at the same time I am directly setting values here

```
NeededSampleData(
                it?.apple?.description,
                it?.description
            )
```

So I am not sure why its not working.

Comment: If your list is empty, the issue comes before the `map` function. `map` *always* returns a list of the same size as it was called on. Kotlin is strongly typed. If there's an uncaught error, it crashes, it doesn't silently give you wrong output.

Comment: You could use ``onEach`` to print/log what you have before you hit the ``map`` operation. It's like ``forEach`` only it passes the collection through at the end, so you can pop it in the chain wherever you like and do side-effects stuff

Comment: Another way you can debug functional chains like this is to insert lines that say `.also(::println)`.